# mIRC Twitch.tv bot points system on and off commands

Tags: bots, points, mirc, twitch

I am currently working on a twitch.tv bot.  What the bot is designed to do is to automatically give points to a user when they join chat on the mIRC end of things.  A timer gets started and they receive 1 point every 30 mins.  The problem with this is I do not want people to afk in the chat with the stream turned off so I would like to put in a command like "!pointstimer start".  When that command is ran I would like it to display a message that the timer has started.  I would like this command to also be op only so others can not run the command at anytime they see fit.  I have the points system in place as well as a raffle system for give aways.  The problem is when I put in commands to turn the points system on and off nothing happens.  I can get it to display text if the command is not op but when it is op then nothing happens.  Here is copies of all of my code.

Code:

```
on *:TEXT:!commands:#: { 
  if ((%floodcommands) || ($($+(%,floodcommands.,$nick),2))) { return }
  set -u10 %floodcommands On
  set -u30 %floodcommands. $+ $nick On
  msg $chan The commands for this channel are the following. !commands, !social, !help, !cop, !hypno, !medic, !vigi, !inno, !gunsmith, !rafflesystem, !donks, !buytickets [number of tickets].   Mod only commands are the following, !donks [add|remove] [user] [number], !raffle [open|close], !roll, !permit [user]. $+
}

on *:TEXT:!social:#: { 
  if ((%floodsocial) || ($($+(%,floodsocial.,$nick),2))) { return }
  set -u10 %floodsocial On
  set -u30 %floodsocial. $+ $nick On
  msg $chan The YouTube page is http://www.youtube.com/user/TheDailyMafia The Twitter page is http://twitter.com/DailyMafia Don't forget to follow and subscribe! $+
}
on *:TEXT:!help:#: { 
  if ((%floodhelp) || ($($+(%,floodhelp.,$nick),2))) { return }
  set -u10 %floodhelp On
  set -u30 %floodhelp. $+ $nick On
  msg $chan To learn the rules of mafia check out $+
}
on *:TEXT:!cop:#: { 
  if ((%floodcop) || ($($+(%,floodcop.,$nick),2))) { return }
  set -u10 %floodcop On
  set -u30 %floodcop. $+ $nick On
  msg $chan Every night the Cop picks a player who is currently alive to investigate or “check”. The mod will then tell the Cop whether that player is town or mafia. Note: the Cop only finds out if the player is town or mafia and is not informed of any special role the player might have. $+
}
on *:TEXT:!medic:#: { 
  if ((%floodmedic) || ($($+(%,floodmedic.,$nick),2))) { return }
  set -u10 %floodmedic On
  set -u30 %floodmedic. $+ $nick On
  msg $chan Every night the Medic picks a player who is currently alive to protect or “save”. This player is protected from 1 KP for that night phase (and that night phase only). If the player is hit with 2 KP the player will still die even if the Medic is protecting them. The Medic may not save himself, and unless otherwise state the Medic may save the same person on consecutive nights. $+
}
on *:TEXT:!hypno:#: { 
  if ((%floodhypno) || ($($+(%,floodhypno.,$nick),2))) { return }
  set -u10 %floodhypno On
  set -u30 %floodhypno. $+ $nick On
  msg $chan The Hypnotist has a one-time use power to use during the night. In order for the power to work both himself and the player the Hypnotist uses it on must be alive at the start of the following day. If the Hypnotists uses his power on you then you become hypnotized and must claim your role at the start of the next day. The first three words out of your mouth must be ‘I am *your role here*’. $+
}
on *:TEXT:!vigi:#: { 
  if ((%floodvigi) || ($($+(%,floodvigi.,$nick),2))) { return }
  set -u10 %floodvigi On
  set -u30 %floodvigi. $+ $nick On
  msg $chan The Vigilante is given a gun with one bullet for the entire game. The Vigilante may choose to shoot someone during the night phase (and only the night phase).  If the Vigilante shoots a player who is medic protected that player will not die and the Vigilante will lose his bullet. If the Vigilante shoots a player who is also shot by the mafia the Vigilante will lose his bullet. $+
}
on *:TEXT:!inno:#: { 
  if ((%floodinno) || ($($+(%,floodinno.,$nick),2))) { return }
  set -u10 %floodinno On
  set -u30 %floodinno. $+ $nick On
  msg $chan The Innocent Child is a vanilla town confirmed at the very start of the game by mod. They have no power. $+
}
on *:TEXT:!gunsmith:#: { 
  if ((%floodgunsmith) || ($($+(%,floodgunsmith.,$nick),2))) { return }
  set -u10 %floodgunsmith On
  set -u30 %floodgunsmith. $+ $nick On
  msg $chan The gunsmith is a town sided role that is allowed to give out a gun during the night which the recipient can then shoot only during the day by saying a command such as, "I Shoot X". The guns have a 1 time use. $+
}
on *:TEXT:!rafflesystem:#: { 
  if ((%floodgunsmith) || ($($+(%,floodgunsmith.,$nick),2))) { return }
  set -u10 %floodgunsmith On
  set -u30 %floodgunsmith. $+ $nick On
  msg $chan We now have a point system for raffles.  You earn Donks by being in chat and watching the games.  To check how many Donks you have use !donks.  When a raffle opens use !buytickets [number of tickets] to buy tickets for the raffle. $+
}
```

Code 2:

```
on *:TEXT:!buytickets &:#:{
  if (!%raffle) { msg $chan Raffle is currently closed! }
  else {
    if ($int($2) < 1) { msg $chan Do you really want to buy no Tickets, $nick $+ ..? }
    elseif ($int($2) > 1000) { msg $chan Sorry $nick but you can only buy up to 1000 raffle tickets at a time. }
    else {
      var %i = 0, %ticket = $int($2)
      var %topic = $+(#,.,$nick), %user = $readini(Points.ini,%topic,Points), %end = 1 * %ticket, %delete = %user - %end
      if (%delete > 0) {
        writeini -n $qt(Points.ini) %topic Points %delete
        while (%i < %ticket) {
          write $qt(Raffle.txt) $nick
          inc %i
        }
        msg $chan $nick you have bought %ticket tickets with %end Donks.
      }
    }
  }
}
on *:TEXT:!raffle &:#:{
  if ($nick isop #) {
    if (($2 == open) && (!%raffle)) || (($2 == close) && (%raffle))  {
      msg $chan RAFFLE IS NOW $replace($upper($2!!),CLOSE,CLOSED)
      if ($2 == open) { set %raffle 1 }
      else unset %raffle
      write -c $qt(Raffle.txt)
    }
  }
}
on *:TEXT:!roll:#:{
  if ($nick isop #) && (%raffle) {
    msg $chan RAFFLE IS NOW BEING ROLLED, GOOD LUCK!!
    .timerCD 1 3 msg $chan /me $!calc( $!timer(CD).reps + 1 ) $!+ !
    .timer 1 4 msg $chan AND THE WINNER IS:
    .timer 1 5 msg $chan $read(Raffle.txt, n)
    unset %raffle
    write -c $qt(Raffle.txt)
  }
}
```

Code 3

```
alias -l addPoints {
  if ($1 !isnum) { echo 2 -st $1 is not a number. It needs to be a number. | halt }
  var %topic $+($chan,.,$nick)
  var %points $calc($readini(Points.ini,%topic,Points) + $1)
  writeini -n Points.ini %topic Points %points
  return %points
}

alias -l lookUpPoints {
  var %topic $+($chan,.,$nick)
  var %points $readini(Points.ini,%topic,Points)
  return %points
}
alias doaddpoints {
  if ($3 !isnum) { echo 2 -st $3 is not a number. It needs to be a number. | halt }
  var %topic $+($1,.,$2)
  var %points $calc($readini(Points.ini,%topic,Points) + $3)
  writeini -n Points.ini %topic Points %points
  echo -a Added points for %topic
}

alias dorempoints {
  var %topic $+($1,.,$2)
  remini -n Points.ini %topic Points
  echo -a Removed points for %topic
}

on *:text:!donks:#:{
  if ((%floodpoints) || ($($+(%,floodpoints.,$nick),2))) { return }
  set -u10 %floodpoints On
  set -u30 %floodpoints. $+ $nick On
  msg # $nick has $readini(Points.ini,$+(#,.,$nick),Points) total donks.
}

on $*:text:/!donks (add|remove)/Si:#:{
  if ($nick isop #) {
    if ($0 < 3) { msg # Insufficient parameters: Use !donks [add|remove] [user] [number] | return }
    writeini -n Points.ini $+(#,.,$3) Points $calc($readini(Points.ini,$+(#,.,$3),Points) $iif($2 == add,+,-) $iif($4 isnum,$4,1))
    { msg $chan $3 now has $readini(Points.ini,$+(#,.,$3),Points) total donks. }
  }
  else { msg $chan This command is only available to moderators. }
}

on *:TEXT:!donktime &:#:{
  if ($nick isop #) {
    if (($2 == start) && (!%donktime)) || (($2 == stop) && (%donktime))  {
      msg $chan DONKTIME IS NOW $replace($upper($2ED!!),CLOSE,CLOSED)
      if ($2 == start) { set %donktime 1 }
      else unset %donktown
    }
  }
}

on !*:join:#:{
  if (!%donktown) {halt}
  else{
  $+(.timerpoints.,#,.,$nick) 0 1800 add.pts $+(#,.,$nick)
  add.pts $+(#,.,$nick)}
}
on !*:part:#:$+(.timerpoints.,#,.,$nick) off
alias -l add.pts {
  writeini -n Points.ini $1 Points $calc($readini(Points.ini,$1,Points) + 1)
}
```

Thank you in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of question doesn't offer any code that we can help you with. You are basically asking us for code without showing us what have you tried so far to acheive it, just what you currently have that doesn't neccessrly related to your request. And for that reason no one as answer or helped you.

I too, was about to move for the next question, but since I wanted to see how were my mSL skills, I decided to give it a go.

**Warning:**

- I over-killed this system in order to sharpen my mSL skills as I said previously.
- The code wasn't fully tested.
- I'm not gonna guide you how to Debug issues nor integrate it into your system, **because** I've built it almost Generic and Dynamic as possible, for easy Debug and Integration, so a person with little experience with mSL should have figure how to use this code for his goals.

**Code:**

```
;###
;### PointsTimer v1
;### - Granting channel user points by fixed interval
;###    Programmer: Orel Eraki
;###    Contact: Orel.Eraki@gmail.com
;###
;### Commands: !PointsTimer START|END|STATUS

#PointsTimer on
alias -l PointsTimer.Name return PointsTimer
alias -l PointsTimer.Description return Granting channel user points by fixed interval.
alias -l PointsTimer.Author return Orel Eraki (Orel.Eraki@gmail.com)
alias -l PointsTimer.Version return 1

;### Settings
alias -l PointsTimer.Channel return #TestTest
alias -l PointsTimer.Idle return 20
alias -l PointsTimer.PointsFile return Points.ini
alias -l PointsTimer.Status return $iif(%PointsTimer, $true, $false)

;### Messages
alias -l PointsTimer.MsgStarted return System has been Started.
alias -l PointsTimer.MsgEnded return System has been Ended.
alias -l PointsTimer.MsgAlreadyStarted return System already been started.
alias -l PointsTimer.MsgNotStarted return System didn't started yet.

;### Events
on *:QUIT: .PointsTimer END-FOR-NICK $nick
on me:*:PART:$($PointsTimer.Channel): .PointsTimer END
on me:*:JOIN:$($PointsTimer.Channel): .PointsTimer END
on !*:PART:$($PointsTimer.Channel): .PointsTimer.SetNickTimer $nick OFF
on !*:JOIN:$($PointsTimer.Channel): {
  if (!$PointsTimer.Status) {
    return
  }
  PointsTimer START-FOR-NICK $nick
}
on *:NICK: {
  if (!$PointsTimer.Status) {
    return
  }
  PointsTimer RENAME $nick $newnick
}

on *:TEXT:!PointsTimer INFO:$($PointsTimer.Channel): {
  PointsTimer.Msg # $PointsTimer.Name v $+ $PointsTimer.Version By $PointsTimer.Author
  PointsTimer.Msg # $PointsTimer.Description
}

on @*:TEXT:!PointsTimer *:$($PointsTimer.Channel): {
  if ($2 == START) {
    if ($PointsTimer.Status) {
      PointsTimer.Msg # $PointsTimer.MsgAlreadyStarted
      return
    }

    PointsTimer START #
    if ($PointsTimer.Status) {
      PointsTimer.Msg # $PointsTimer.MsgStarted
    }
  }
  else if ($2 == END) {
    if (!$PointsTimer.Status) {
      PointsTimer.Msg # $PointsTimer.MsgNotStarted
      return
    }
    PointsTimer END #
    if (!$PointsTimer.Status) {
      PointsTimer.Msg # $PointsTimer.MsgEnded
    }
  }
  elseif ($2 == STATUS) {
    PointsTimer.Msg # System is currently $iif($PointsTimer.Status, ON, OFF)
  }
}

;### Commands
alias PointsTimer {
  if ($1 == START) {
    if ($PointsTimer.Status || $2 !ischan) {
      return
    }

    inc %PointsTimer
    PointsTimer.SetNicksTimer $PointsTimer.GetChannelNicks($2)
  }
  elseif ($1 == END) {
    if (!$PointsTimer.Status) {
      return
    }

    unset %PointsTimer
    .timerPointsTimer.* off
  }
  elseif ($1 == START-FOR-NICK) {
    if (!$PointsTimer.Status || !$ial($+($2,!*@*))) {
      return
    }

    PointsTimer.SetNickTimer $2
  }
  elseif ($1 == END-FOR-NICK) {
    if (!$PointsTimer.Status) {
      return
    }

    PointsTimer.SetNickTimer $2 OFF
  }
  elseif ($1 == RENAME) {
    .timer 1 0 PointsTimer END-FOR-NICK $2
    .timer 1 1 PointsTimer START-FOR-NICK $3
  }
  else {
    PointsTimer.Echo Unknown command $1
  }
}

alias -l PointsTimer.Msg msg $1 * PointsTimer: $2-
alias -l PointsTimer.Echo echo $color(info) -agt * PointsTimer: $1-

alias -l PointsTimer.GetChannelNicks {
  if ($1 !ischan) {
    return
  }

  var %i = 1, %n = $nick($1, 0)
  var %results
  while (%i <= %n) {
    %results = $addtok(%results, $nick($1, %i), 44)
    inc %i
  }
  return %results
}

alias -l PointsTimer.SetNickTimer $+(.timerPointsTimer.,$1) $iif($2 == OFF, OFF,0 $PointsTimer.Idle Add.PTS $1)

alias -l PointsTimer.SetNicksTimer {
  var %results
  var %i = 1, %n = $numtok($1, 44)
  while (%i <= %n) {
    PointsTimer.SetNickTimer $gettok($1, %i, 44)
    inc %i
  }
}

alias -l Add.PTS writeini -n $PointsTimer.PointsFile $1 Points $calc($readini($PointsTimer.PointsFile, $1, Points) + 1)
#PointsTimer End
```